# partitions and their generating functions and Partitions of n

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, contest-math

A partition of an integer, n, is one way of writing n as the sum of positive integers where the order of the addends (terms being added) does not matter. p(n, k) = number of partitions of n with k parts. p(4,2)= 2, because (2+2) , (1+3).

i want to find a recurrence relation for p(n,k)?

i read some note about Ferrer diagram, but i couldn't find such recurrence.

any hint or idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** the partition either has a 1 for one of its parts, or it doesn't.

**Answer:** If one of the parts is 1, then the remaining $k-1$ parts partition $n-1$, so there are $p(n-1,k-1)$ partitions where at least one part is 1. Otherwise, every part is at least 2: removing one from each part leaves a partition of $n-k$ into $k$ parts, so there are $p(n-k,k)$ of these partitions. These are all possible cases, proving the recurrence
$$
p(n,k) = p(n-1,k-1) + p(n-k,k)
$$

Comment: I'll give an example: given the partition (5,4,3) of 12, removing one from each part gives the partition (4,3,2) of 9. So if the original partition is $(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots,\lambda_k)$, the new one is $(\lambda_1-1,\lambda_2-1,\dots,\lambda_k-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is actually slightly easier to compute $p(n,k)$ as the number of partitions of $n$ with $k$ as largest part; that this is the same number as in the question follows from the transposition of Ferrers diagrams.

Now removing the part $k$, we are left with a partition of $n-k$ into parts *at most* equal to $k$; define $p'$ by the relation $p(n,k)=p'(n-k,k)$. Now a partition with parts at most equal to $k$ either has a part $k$, or is a partition with parts at most equal to $k-1$:
$$
p′(m,k)=p(m,k)+p′(m,k-1)
$$
The case $k=0$ is easy to handle. From this you can work out a recursion for $p(n,k)$.

Comment: Yes: back to the original problem reduce a partition with $k>0$ parts either by removing a part equal to $1$ (leaving a partition of $n-1$ into $k-1$ parts), or if there is no such part, subtract $1$ unit from all $k$ parts, leaving a partition of $n-k$ into $k$ parts. Now you can understand the answer by user153695 as well, I hope!